# CAPTCHA Problems?

Tags: support, captcha

These days, whenever I encounter a CAPTCHA, instead of verifying with pictures or the usual, 85 tells me download apps and run them for 30 seconds. These apps usually require a monthly subscription and other things I'm not willing to do. Is it just me, or are there also people out there with the same problem?

Comment: I think you have a virus or some malware on your computer, or your ISP is injecting advertisements into the page. This isn't an issue on SE's side.

Comment: Just you. SE does not do those things.